# How use TabItem through TabLayout in Android

Tags: android, material-design, android-tablayout, androiddesignsupport

Recently google added `android.support.design.widget.TabItem` in `supportDesign` as [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabItem.html) said:

> TabItem is a special 'view' which allows you to declare tab items for
>   a TabLayout within a layout. This view is not actually added to
>   TabLayout, it is just a dummy which allows setting of a tab items's
>   text, icon and custom layout.

But when I add `TabItems` to my `TabLayout`:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="match_parent">

     <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
             android:text="@string/tab_text"/>

     <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
             android:icon="@drawable/ic_android"/>

 </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

Nothing displayed (in fact place of Tabs exist but Icon/Text not). Does any one knows How to use `TabItem` through xml?

Comment: I agree, Google's documentation about this topic is so inadequate, it borders on negligence. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout

Comment: this answer will help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38035415/550471

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37712489/1462770) answer, TabItem with `tabLayout.setupViewPager` have conflict and Icons disappear. To make it work you should implement two methods like following and avoid using `setupViewPager` method:

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(position).select();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: Note that setOnTabSelectedListener  is deprecated and you should use addOnTabSelectedListener as it is discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38498882/1476228).

Answer (score 0):

you should set these attributes for the TabItems

```
android:layout_width
android:layout_height
```

Cheers

Comment: I set this attrs ( in fact if you dont set them A.S gives you error)

Comment: Hmm..strange.In my case I use a RelativeLayout (it doesnt matter which layout you use) which contains the TabLayout and TabItems. I set these attrs and the icons and everything displays.
I'm using 23.2.1 support library

Comment: Can you put it in github?