# How sync TabLayout with ViewPager when using TabItem

Tags: android, material-design, android-tablayout, android-support-design

I want to use `TabLayout` with `TabItem` with following code:

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/color_primary"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/gray_light">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_language" />


        <!-- other tabs ... -->


    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

And this is show me Icons correctly like this:

[image]

But the problem is when I want to add my `TabLayout` to `ViewPager`, with following code, all of them exist and clickable but disappear. Did I miss something?

```
 MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
 pager.setAdapter(adapter);

 tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
```

and this is result:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager)` is going to do is call `getPageTitle()` on the view pager's adapter and create tabs with the strings that are returned.  I would recommend not calling `setupWithViewPager()`. Then you will need to do two things:

- Call `viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener` with an `OnPageChangeListener` implementation that will select the tab based on the selected page.
- Call `tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener` with an `OnTabSelectedListener` implementation that will call `viewPager.setCurrentPage()` with the selected tab number.

Just make sure your `PagerAdapter` count matches the number of tabs in your `TabLayout`.

Comment: Thanks and nice work-around. I think this is messy way to handle this But it's solve the problem :D

Answer (score 28):

**This is helpful :**

/////// Syncing!!!

Replace

```
setupWithViewPager();
```

With

```
tablayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager));
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tablayout));
```

Comment: This can help  other people !! @Pierre.Vriens

Comment: Jeez... thanks bro... I spent hours banging my head on that. There is literally no samples for that on the internets.