# How is TabItem used when placed in the layout XML?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabs, android-tablayout

The [`TabLayout` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) gives an example of nesting `TabItem` directly inside `TabLayout` like so:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
         android:text="@string/tab_text"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_android"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

But it gives no example of how this could be used in practice, and the documentation for TabItem says:

> This view is not actually added to TabLayout, it is just a dummy which allows setting of a tab items's text, icon and custom layout.

So what is `TabItem` for? After extensive Googling, I cannot find a single example of anyone defining TabItems in XML. Is there any way to set up a tabbed activity using TabItem in the resource file as shown above?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This appears to be a relatively recent addition to the design library, apparently added in version 23.2.0, though it's not mentioned in [the revision history](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html). It's functionality is pretty basic, and the only attributes it seems to use are the three given in its [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabItem.html): `text`, `icon`, and `layout`.

From testing, it seems it's basically an XML shortcut for creating a new `Tab`, and setting its text, icon, and custom `View`, as one would usually do in code. When it says "This view is not actually added to TabLayout", I believe it's meant to suggest that it's not a `View` in the regular sense, in that you can't set any kind of standard layout attribute on it, like `layout_width` or `background`. It simply serves to cause the `TabLayout` to create a new `Tab` for each `TabItem`, and call `setText()`, `setIcon()`, and `setCustomView()` accordingly.

For example, to add a `Tab` in code, we would usually do something like this:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

// Add Tab
TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.newTab();

tab.setCustomView(R.layout.tab);
tab.setText("Tab 1");
tab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

tabLayout.addTab(tab);
```

Whereas now we can replace everything after the comment above by adding a `TabItem` in the layout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout="@layout/tab"
        android:text="Tab 1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

Do note that the same requirements for the custom `View` layout still apply. That is, the `TextView` for the text must have the system Resource ID `@android:id/text1`, and the `ImageView` for the icon must have the ID `@android:id/icon`. As an example, the `R.layout.tab` from above:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView android:id="@android:id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In TabItem your example, you define the layout attribute in addition setting text and icon. Are you saying that Android knows to apply the text attribute ("Tab 1") into your custom layout's TextView ("@android:id/text1")?

Comment: Yep, exactly. That's why the `TextView` and the `ImageView` need to have those specific IDs. That's just how it works in code, too, if you've ever set custom `View`s on `Tab`s.

Comment: Thanks! If this were to be set up with a ViewPager, would you just pass your TabLayout object into the adapter so that it can inform the ViewPager about the existing tabs? Any way to integrate them without having the ViewPager auto-populate the TabLayout as is usually done?

Comment: Hmm, with a `ViewPager` I'm thinking you're gonna have to handle the setup yourself, since, I believe, the `TabLayout` can't use a custom `View` when self-populating its `Tab`s, and the texts get pulled from the `PagerAdapter` automatically. There might be some palatable way to do this, but I'll have to think on it for a bit.

Comment: Is there an alternative to a ViewPager? What practical application does TabItem have?

Comment: You don't have to use `TabLayout` with a `ViewPager`. It's just a specialized `View` that shows tabs. With its `OnTabSelectedListener` interface, you can hook it up to whatever you want, really. `TabItem` might be handy if, e.g., you just need a simple interface with only a couple of predetermined states, and you don't wanna mess with setting up a `ViewPager` and a `PagerAdapter`. Personally, I probably wouldn't ever use them with a `ViewPager`, since overriding the default auto-populate behavior would end up taking more code than what would be saved by using `TabItem`s.

Comment: When you say you can hook it up to whatever you want, what do you have in mind? Is there a practical alternative to ViewPager?

Comment: I pretty much mean whatever you want. It's basically a glorified `RadioGroup`. If you want to use it to swap out `View`s, you could  use it to control a `ViewFlipper` or `ViewSwitcher`, but those don't have swipe built in. Or you could do basic `View` manipulation, with `ViewGroup#addView()` and `removeView()`. Or you could perform your own `FragmentTransaction`s, but, again, no swipe unless you implement it.

Comment: @MikeM. How do you set a background that changes according to the state of the tab. Is it possible ?? I couldn't figure out a way.

Comment: @SagarDevanga Old comment question, but here is an answer: The goal of TabItem as part of the support design library is to achieve the proposed [material design guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/components/tabs.html). Following those, an active tab is marked by a colored underline (matching the text/icon highlight). It can be adjusted as `app:tabIndicatorColor` on `TabLayout`. It is also automatically animated when switching tabs by swipe. I would suggest sticking to the guidelines. Otherwise, try to create a custom view as shown by @MikeM. with a selector as background.

Comment: this is the only post I could find that mentions `TabItem` and uses the `android:layout` parameter. Where could I find a larger example of the layout xml file ?

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere I'm not sure what you mean, or why you'd need a "larger example". It doesn't really get much more complicated than what is shown in my answer. Note that the `layout` attribute is for the _tabs_ themselves, not the _pages_.

Comment: thanks for the fast response, I was so disappointed when I found out the layout attribute is only for the tabs. (By "larger" I meant the rest of the layout beyond the tab)

Answer (score 3):

Quick addition to @Mikes very helpful answer:

Android Studio now has a Template on how to use a `TabLayout` with `TabItem` setup in an XML layout. Create all needed files with **"New > Activity > Tabbed Activity"** and choose **"Action Bar Tabs(with ViewPager)"** as shown in the screenshot:

[image: Configure Tabbed Activity Template in Android Studio]

If you want to adjust the look of the `TabItem` without a custom view: use **white vector assets** as tab `android:icon` and **tint** them with a selector (providing different colors based on `android:state_selected`)

The color of the line under the currently selected tab is set as `app:tabIndicatorColor` on tag `TabLayout`.

It took me a while to get it to work, so the complete steps turned into such a long answer that I don't want to copy them here. You can find my more detailed answer with full code at:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49603559/414581

Comment: It seems that you can't select "Navigation Style" anymore. The current template doesn't contain "TabItem". I've been searching for hours how to use it because I hoped I could just put my fragments into the TabItems and do it without any adapter... :/

Answer (score 0):

[image]

please see com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem class it accepts icon text from attributes, but seems like you will need to add Tags on runtime.