# setOnTabSelectedListener is deprecated

Tags: android

I always see a crossed out line <s>setOnTabSelectedListener</s> for the following code

```
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }
}
```

And the error shown is:

> setOnTabSelectedListener is deprecated

However, the program seems to work just fine. May I know what's going on?

Answer (score 214, accepted):

> May i know whats going on ?

Deprecated means that they decided this is not a good way to do it or they have found a better way of doing it, and this deprecated method will be removed in the future.

The fix is to use [addOnTabSelectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#addOnTabSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener)) instead of <s>[setOnTabSelectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setOnTabSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener))</s>.
It works almost the same way.

The difference is that with `addOnTabSelectedListener`:

- you can add multiple listeners. With `setOnTabSelectedListener` you could only have one.
- you should remove the listener when you're done with it, with [removeOnTabSelectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#removeOnTabSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener)).

---

General rule of thumb: never use deprecated methods.

Comment: upvote for detailed answer covering all points, but I think 'fix is to use addOnTabSelectedListener' should be in bold to quickly find the answer

Comment: @ShirishHerwade my goal is not to provide a quick answer, but to provide a complete answer. I think the explanation is as important as the solution :-)

Comment: Thank @Tim Castelijns it's helpfu but when am i supposed to use removeOnTabSelectedListener.? is it on onTabUnselected or onTabReselected?

Comment: @eLi you use that when you no longer want to listen to tabSelected events. In practice, this is almost never required

Answer (score 21):

As `setOnTabSelectedListener` is deprecated now, you can use the new method

```
addOnTabSelectedListener(OnTabSelectedListener)
```

This change allows to add multiple tab selection listeners to a single `TabLayout`.

Comment: Any use case scenario for multiple listeners?

Comment: What do you mean? For adding multiple listeners, just add each listener with this method

Answer (score 10):

in kotlin usage like below code;

```
   tabLayoutView.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
                override fun onTabReselected(p0: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                }

                override fun onTabUnselected(p0: TabLayout.Tab?) {

                }

                override fun onTabSelected(p0: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                    viewPager.currentItem = tabLayoutView.selectedTabPosition
                }


            })
```

Answer (score 5):

Use below codes instead :

```
tablayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager));
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tablayout));
```

**And if you want to sync them when clicking on tabs or swiping the viewpager above codes are the key for syncing.**