# Hide search view when tab is changed

Tags: android, tabs, searchview

I have two tabs, one tab contains **news headlines** and other **categories**. User can search only news headlines. So I want to **hide search view** when user opens **categories** tab.
I tried this but not working !

```
@Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            if(tab.getPosition() == 1)
                searchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }
```

Below is my code.

```
private void initialize(){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sec_main);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    NavigationDrawer navigationDrawer_fragment =
            (NavigationDrawer) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mainfragmentdrawer);
    navigationDrawer_fragment.setup((DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);
    final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Latest"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Categories"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}
```

initializing search view

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.refresh_activity, menu);
    MenuItem itm = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) itm.getActionView();
}
```

Comment: **FYI** [`setOnTabSelectedListener` is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38498788/setontabselectedlistener-is-deprecated)

Comment: @NileshRathod but I am showing toast and it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add an `else` statement to your `onTabSelected` because if you set the visibility once, it will not go back to its original form since it is a tab layout. But first you need to set a `Boolean` to tell the menuItem if it should be shown or not.

```
private boolean searchViewShown = false;

@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
  if(tab.getPosition() == 1) {
     searchViewShown = false;
  } else {
     searchViewShown = true;
  }

  invalidateOptionsMenu();
  viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}
```

**Update**

It seems that your `SearchView` is a menuItem. In that case you need to add `onPrepareOptionsMenu`, and set here the visibility of your `searchView` like:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem itm = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    if (searchViewShown) {
        itm.setVisible(true);
    } else { 
        itm.setVisible(false);
    }
    return true
}
```

Then add `invalidateOptionsMenu()` whenever you select a tab, so that it calls the `onPrepareOptionsMenu` and check if your searchView will be shown or not.

Comment: not hiding search view but is showing toast in both when I change

Comment: @teptis still not hiding

Comment: lil bit working, now I am on tab1 and when i click on search it's working but on tab2 when I press search icon it expands but I can't type anything. I also want to hide search icon also

Comment: @UbaidTanoli - It seems that View.GONE is not working. You can try my updated answer. I use `setVisible(Boolean)` for menuItem.