# Crash on setOnTabSelectedListener with com.android.support:design:28.0.0

Tags: android, android-tablayout, androiddesignsupport

I'm using a library with a class that extends TabLayout. I'm trying to build with the latest support libraries:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v14:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0'
```

This results in a crash:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setOnTabSelectedListener(Landroid/support/design/widget/TabLayout$OnTabSelectedListener;)
```

This is the source from the decompiled `TabLayout.class` file (It doesn't seem to have a source jar like other versions):

```
/** @deprecated */
@Deprecated
public void setOnTabSelectedListener(@Nullable TabLayout.BaseOnTabSelectedListener listener) { ... }

public interface OnTabSelectedListener extends TabLayout.BaseOnTabSelectedListener<TabLayout.Tab> {
}

public interface BaseOnTabSelectedListener<T extends TabLayout.Tab> { ... }
```

It works with 27.1.1 and earlier versions where the source looks like so:

```
/**
 * @deprecated Use {@link #addOnTabSelectedListener(OnTabSelectedListener)} and
 * {@link #removeOnTabSelectedListener(OnTabSelectedListener)}.
 */
@Deprecated
public void setOnTabSelectedListener(@Nullable OnTabSelectedListener listener) { ... }

/**
 * Callback interface invoked when a tab's selection state changes.
 */
public interface OnTabSelectedListener { ... }
```

I'm running in Genymotion with Samsung Galaxy S8 - API 26 - 1440x2960.

I'm not sure if there's an issue with the design:28.0.0 library or maybe I'm just doing something wrong in the build. It seems to work OK with earlier versions. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Try using `addOnTabSelectedListener(OnTabSelectedListener)` instead of `setOnTabSelectedListener(...)`

Comment: Thanks but the call is not in my code. It's in the framework I am using - ResearchStack.

Comment: Strange. Doc didn't mentioned it was removed. I decompiled the class from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/design/28.0.0 (AAR) file and that method is still there... It is deprecated.. not removed.

Answer (score 4):

I downloaded the AAR file from both versions: [27.1.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/design/27.1.1) and [28.0.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/design/28.0.0):

Decompiling the TabLayout.class from both packages, I could see its signature has changed from:

**27.1.1**

```
@Deprecated
public void setOnTabSelectedListener(@Nullable TabLayout.BaseOnTabSelectedListener listener)
}
```

**28.0.0**

```
@Deprecated
public void setOnTabSelectedListener(@Nullable TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener listener) {
}
```

So, now, that method is expecting a `BaseOnTabSelectedListener` and not `OnTabSelectedListener`

The old `onTabSelectedListener` does not implements the new `BaseOnTabSelectedListener`

So, probably have to import the material component as well which have the new implementation of `OnTabSelectedListener`:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

[Doc of old](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener) `onTabSelectedListener` (does not implements `BaseOnTabSelectedListener`

[Doc of new](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/package-summary) `onTabSelectedListener` (implements `BaseOnTabSelectedListener`).

Sorry but I did not directly show how to fix it because I'm not able to go further right now. But that is the root cause I guess.

Comment: Thanks. I think this solution as well as using addOnTabSelectedListener would work if I was writing the class; however, I'm using a class implemented by a framework: public class IconTabLayout extends android.support.design.widget.TabLayout, and material:1.0.0 provides com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout which isn't going to help me unless I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * @deprecated Use {@link #addOnTabSelectedListener(OnTabSelectedListener)} and
 * {@link #removeOnTabSelectedListener(OnTabSelectedListener)}.
 */
```

It is-was [depreciated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout#setOnTabSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener)) in API level `26.1.0` perhaps that's why you get this error.

To fix that, use [**`addOnTabSelectedListener`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#addOnTabSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener)) instead of **[`setOnTabSelectedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setOnTabSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener))**

Refer [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38498882/4409113).

Example code:

```
tablayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager));
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tablayout));
```

As a note, don't use depreciated methods.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the new Material Components dependencies. With this one everything works fine and you just need to add one line in Gradle to import all design components.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

With this one line dependency RecyclerView, CardView, TabLayout, and all of view components come available. You also will have Chips, CardView, RecyclerView, tec.

Remember that:

> You should not use the com.android.support and
>   com.google.android.material dependencies in your app at the same time

Check it here about how to setup: https://medium.com/nyc-design/material-design-components-setup-on-android-studio-3-2-8b3194d9bebf

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the main question.